# PEM encoded certificate conversion in iOS

Tags: swift, openssl, rsa, pem, der

In my app I get a PEM encoded certificate and need to convert it into a different form to later use it for JWT verification purposes. The result I'm looking for is either a SecKey representation of the public key contained in the certificate, PEM Public Key string or conversion to a DER certificate.

I am very VERY new to this, so I have no idea how to tackle the problem. I've Googled around and found no clear solution, even Apple documentation only mentions DER certificates. If I understand it correctly, one solution would be to use OpenSSL inside my app (is this even possible?) for conversions, but I couldn't find any useful resource on how to implement this so I would appreciate more insight on the right practice.

Making conversions outside the application is not an option for my case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have a certificate in PEM format, you can obtain it's  DER encoded data by stripping away the header and footer lines and base64-decoding the text in between them (don't forget to discard line breaks as well). [1, 2]

You can then use [`SecCertificateCreateWithData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1396073-seccertificatecreatewithdata) from the iOS Security API to create a `SecCertificate` to use in your app like so:

```
// example data from http://fm4dd.com/openssl/certexamples.htm
let pem = """
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIIC2jCCAkMCAg38MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGbMQswCQYDVQQGEwJKUDEOMAwG
    (...)
    +tZ9KynmrbJpTSi0+BM=
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    """

// remove header, footer and newlines from pem string

let certData = Data(base64Encoded: pemWithoutHeaderFooterNewlines)!

guard let certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, data as CFData) else {
    // handle error
}

// use certificate e.g. copy the public key
let publicKey = SecCertificateCopyKey(certificate)!
```

---

[[1]](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/PEM.html#PEM-ENCRYPTION-FORMAT)

> PEM format is simply base64 encoded data surrounded by header lines.

[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_filename_extensions)

> .pem – Base64 encoded DER certificate, enclosed between "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"

Comment: hi I think you have to change the `data as CFData` with `certData as CFData` and one more can you please help to change the Philips Hue pem into .der https://developers.meethue.com/develop/application-design-guidance/using-https/

Comment: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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Comment: ItRnKfqWKnHFGmShPaQ7MDkxCzAJBgNVBAYTAk5MMRQwEgYDVQQKDAtQaGlsaXBz
IEh1ZTEUMBIGA1UEAwwLcm9vdC1icmlkZ2WCFDuxUi22sYpLlwJY81Wrqy11phcO
MAoGCCqGSM49BAMCA0gAMEUCIEBYYEOsa07TH7E5MJnGw557lVkORgit2Rm1h3B2
sFgDAiEA1Fj/C3AN5psFMjo0//mrQebo0eKd3aWRx+pQY08mk48=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: Find the complete data image link https://ibb.co/R7jYKL9