# PEM-encoded Elliptic Curve public key conversion iOS

Tags: ios, swift, pem, asn.1, seckeyref

In an iOS application, I receive a PEM-encoded Elliptic curve public key.
I would like to create a `SecKey` object from it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51479106/pem-encoded-certificate-conversion-in-ios) question has been very useful to get **RSA key** parsing to work.

But I struggle adapting it to work with an **EC key**.

## Example working with an RSA key

```
var secKeyCreateError : Unmanaged<CFError>?
guard
    let stringPublicKey = Data(
        base64Encoded: "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAhT0OXGhPWpbrZBTIScIFQVooi/Qo/NyTYRnrIyZ42nksKCBeSOBu+FPOHCI5U4RUSc2cUOe83dyuKmboU2Kdc1dTq9HDAau3dhpE7VLzZKzMHay+8XW5V6kQJ2oOIGKJphsjJLDM5KxCr5etHEHE5rfrPIBZA0sgcvyT0TsavOAhr55Eu4U2fu8SefxM4CWobXKANiWbmSzzYbo2EIZrfhhe2RncwnH5kr0PMk6Q+kEcuRt58VyYoDAa7vRQvY+KDwxE81CCkIjKpJ55f4uN0/VDclXzFjK8FeOgIiH3n8KD6xqtkvmFc+M8tEJYlzdHWIRN7VoNqbn4IoevnziYhQIDAQAB"
    ),
    let peerPublicKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(
        stringPublicKey as CFData,
        [
            kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
            kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
        ] as CFDictionary,
        &secKeyCreateError
    )
else {
    NSLog("Failed to create SecKey : %@", secKeyCreateError!.takeRetainedValue().localizedDescription)
    return
}

NSLog("SecKey successfully created")
```

## Example failing with an EC key

```
var secKeyCreateError : Unmanaged<CFError>?
guard
    let stringPublicKey = Data(
        base64Encoded: "MHYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEACIDYgAEhYvCTeKdth6ffyCKReeO7cJSfN94BfieZ/9zkE6sDFz/ZifyMkgeg7mq8XB4UYn7aSEcsnqFNswROLnU4NqVFbmGDi5wAI0jRazdskGFBf+0R/zIPozZgJOSrREMEqi7"
    ),
    let peerPublicKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(
        stringPublicKey as CFData,
        [
            kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
            kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
        ] as CFDictionary,
        &secKeyCreateError
    )
else {
    NSLog("Failed to create SecKey : %@", secKeyCreateError!.takeRetainedValue().localizedDescription)
    return
}

NSLog("SecKey successfully created")
```

Execution returns the following logs :

```
[seckey] SecKeyCreate init(ECPublicKey) failed: -26275
Failed to create SecKey : The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -50 - EC public key creation from data failed)
```

**For information**, I used https://mkjwk.org/ to generate public keys.

## What else did I try

I tried to extract the DER BIT STRING using [ASN1Decoder](https://github.com/filom/ASN1Decoder) and [ASN1Swift](https://github.com/tikhop/ASN1Swift) without success.

Would you have any idea of what's going on with those EC keys ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [pointed out by CyonAlexRdx here](https://github.com/Yubico/yubikit-ios/issues/120), a SECG key **must be** in **X9.63** format to be imported using **Security Framework**.

Here, we are in trouble because Key is in **PEM** format. I identified 2 solutions.

## Your project uses Swift Package Manager

you may import it using **CryptoKit**, then map it to a **Security Framework** object.

> Detailed explainations [from eskimo on developer.apple.com forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/680572)

1. Import the PEM key using Apple CryptoKit.
2. Get the X9.63 representation.
3. Create the Security framework key from that.

For example, the following routine imports a PEM secp256r1 private key and returns a SecKey object:

```swift
func createSecKeyWithPEMSecp256r1Private(_ pem: String) throws -> SecKey {
    let privateKeyCK = try P256.Signing.PrivateKey(pemRepresentation: pem)
    let x963Data = privateKeyCK.x963Representation
    var errorQ: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
    guard let privateKeySF = SecKeyCreateWithData(x963Data as NSData, [
        kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
        kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
    ] as NSDictionary, &errorQ) else {
        throw errorQ!.takeRetainedValue()
    }
    return privateKeySF
}
```

## Your project uses cocoapods

You can use [ASN1Decoder](https://cocoapods.org/pods/ASN1Decoder) to extract key data (in x9.63 format) from DER.

```swift
import ASN1Decoder

class DerDecoder {
    func decodePublicKey(_ data: Data,  _ error: UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFError>?>?) -> SecKey? {
        guard
            let asn1 = try? ASN1DERDecoder.decode(data: data),
            let keyData = asn1.first?.sub(1)?.value as? Data
        else {
            return nil
        }
        return SecKeyCreateWithData(
            keyData as CFData,
            [
                kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
                kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
            ] as CFDictionary,
            error
        )
    }
}


var secKeyCreateError : Unmanaged<CFError>?
guard
    let stringPublicKey = Data(
        base64Encoded: "MHYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEACIDYgAEhYvCTeKdth6ffyCKReeO7cJSfN94BfieZ/9zkE6sDFz/ZifyMkgeg7mq8XB4UYn7aSEcsnqFNswROLnU4NqVFbmGDi5wAI0jRazdskGFBf+0R/zIPozZgJOSrREMEqi7"
    ),
    let peerPublicKey = DerDecoder().decodePublicKey(
        stringPublicKey,
        &secKeyCreateError,
    )
else {
    NSLog("Failed to create SecKey : %@", secKeyCreateError!.takeRetainedValue().localizedDescription)
    return
}

NSLog("SecKey successfully created")
```